# Why do we allow the base class to cast to the derived class?

Tags: c++

We all know that the base class can't be converted to a derived class, but as the code shows, we did, and we got the result B::foo() and A::fun(), how to interpret this Situation? (Why are B::foo() and A::fun()?)

```
#pragma
#include "pch.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        printf("A::foo()\n");
    }
    virtual void fun()
    {
        printf("A::fun()\n");
    }
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        printf("B::foo()\n");
    }
    void fun()
    {
        printf("B::fun()\n");
    }
};
int main(void)
{
    A a;
    B *pb = (B*)&a;
    pb->foo();
    pb->fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior at best. Compiler will let you do this, but how the program will behave at runtime is anyone's guess.

Comment: You can cast /any/ object to another object if you want. This is inherited from C and still there for historical reasons... But that you can do something doesn't mean it's good. Like said, this is undefined behavior. Will likely lead to segmentation faults...

Comment: normaly when you do something like this you would use dynamic cast and you would define the behaviour of this downcast you can do alot of weird stuff in c++ which result in undifined behaviour c++ is hard and you always have to keep an eye on if the stuff that you are doing makes sense

Comment: The second line of `main()` does `B *pb = (B*)&a;` which forces conversion of the pointer to the base (`&a`) to a pointer to derived. The compiler doesn't issue a diagostic because your code effectively directs it not to.   Since `a` is not an instance of `A`, the subsequent usage of `pb` give undefined behaviour.

Comment: Just a sidenote: You should not use a C-style cast in C++, use `static_cast<>`, `dynamic_cast<>` or `reinterpret_cast<>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior territory.

You get the same behavior by declaring the B::fun() to be virtual *and removing the inheritance from `A`*.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        printf("A::foo()\n");
    }
    virtual void fun()
    {
        printf("A::fun()\n");
    }
};
class B
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        printf("B::foo()\n");
    }
    virtual void fun()
    {
        printf("B::fun()\n");
    }
};
int main(void)
{
    A a;
    B *pb = (B*)&a;
    pb->foo();
    pb->fun();
    return 0;
}
```

This is likely due to the behavior of the [VTable](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/). Since A has a virtual function, it has  `__vptr` storing the location of the VTable, where virtual functions can be looked up. When the `void fun()` function becomes virtual in `B`, it means that it follows the `__vptr` to check the VTable for a pointer to the `void fun()` function. Since the `__vptr` in `A` points to the `A` VTable, it follows the the pointer to `void fun()` will point to `A::fun()`.

In other words, you're playing with the how the internal representation of things happen to look and getting lucky based on this internal representation. Similarly pointing a `B*` and any other piece of memory could work if the memory happens to contain similar enough information to a `B` that the program could work with it. It will however fail if you try to do more complex stuff (such as accessing variables defined in `B`).

Comment: When pb is forced to be converted with B*, why is the virtual function table of pb lookup still A?

Comment: According to the link I posted: "Consequently, it makes each class object allocated bigger by the size of one pointer." In other words, the pointer to the VTable is stored in the allocated memory for A when A is created. Casting to B does not change the underlying memory which points to As VTable.

Answer (score 2):

> We all know that the base class can't be converted to a derived class

That's not 100% true. Well, it is true as stated. But then in your example you show us "pointer casts", not "type casts". And these are a bit different. This code is completely valid:

```
B b;
A* a = (A*)&b;
B* b2 = (B*)a;
```

The third line is correct, because we know that `a` is actually pointing to an instance of `B`. This behaviour is sometimes useful (e.g. a dispatcher).

> but as the code shows, we did, and we got the result B::foo() and A::fun(), how to interpret this Situation?

Your code, on the other hand has undefined behaviour inside it. You start with object of type `A`, you take `A*` and you downcast it to `B*`. The compiler will allow you to do that because in general, as I said earlier this actually can be a correct code under certain circumstances (and it is hard for a compiler to detect these). But not in your case, in your case the result of this operation is not defined in terms of the C++ standard.

All in all: you should interpret it as an incorrect code that does random and dangerous stuff. And it needs fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Your example invokes undefined behavior by invalid pointer cast.

```cpp
A a;
B *pb = (B*)&a;
```

As you are using a C-style cast, it's hard to see which cast is exactly used, that's why C++ introduced specific casts. `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` both result in UB after any usage of `pb`, as variable `a` is NOT an instance of `B`. Anything that happens from here on now is compilers choice, it can crash, it can work, etc.

As your `A` class has a `virtual` method, you  can use `dynamic_cast`, to check at runtime if your pointer points to an instance of `B`.

```cpp
if(B* ptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(&a){
   // Use ptr, we know it's not null here
}
```

`dynamic_cast` will return a `nullptr` if the cast fails.